# Adding In-App Products

Tags: android

I added the Billing class files, the IInAppBillingService.aidl file into com.android.vending.billing package, and the com.android.vending.BILLING permission.  After trying to add the apk in the developer console, it shows that the permission is required; but it won't let me add inapp products.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "the permission is required"? That the permission is recognized by the developers console and correctly added? Or that it isn't correctly added? What is not working with adding inapp products? Do you get a specific error? Please if possible make your question a bit more clear.

Comment: I add the signed apk.  When adding the signed apk to developer console before saving the new apk, it shows I have added the billing permission.  I save the new apk which removes the old apk, and attempt to add inapp products.  It says I need to add a signed apk that has the billing permission.

Comment: I just created a new application.  Added the same apk, and it now allows me to add inapp products.  It looks like its a bug.  After adding an additional apk, google isn't updating their system.